# Deriving the thickness of a line on a grid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let's say we have a line going through the centers of two cells on a 2D grid, and we define a "pixel-perfect rasterized line" as the minimal set of 8-connected cells that best approximate the original line.

Finding such a set of cells is usually done via the [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), but in some cases [[1](https://forum.unity.com/threads/linerenderer2d-gpu-pixel-perfect-2d-line-renderer-for-unity-urp-2d-renderer.1021708/), [2](https://godotengine.org/qa/59697/how-to-properly-draw-a-1px-wide-line-at-any-angle-possible-bug), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501795/drawing-aliased-pixel-perfect-lines-in-fragment-shader)] it can be useful to have some closed-form formula e.g. $$\text{distance(point, line)} \,<\, \text{thickness}/2,$$that tells whether a given cell's center belongs to such "rasterized line" or not.

For this purpose, $\text{thickness} = 1$ doesn't always give correct results, but empirically I found that $$\text{thickness} = \max(|N_x|, |N_y|)$$ (where $N$ is the normalized direction of the line) seems to always work.

**Illustration of the correct (green) and incorrect (red) results:**

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have enough mathematical background to understand *why* this ends up being the correct answer. How would one actually derive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Turned out to be much simpler than I assumed :-)

To get the desired result, we just have to make sure that no two adjacent cells along the slower-varying coordinate can pass the distance test at the same time. I.e. *thickness along that coordinate* must be equal to 1, so the "euclidean distance" thickness would be the projection of a unit vector along that coordinate on the direction perpendicular to the line.